# Is there a way to create GUI component in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing GUI in Python using Tkinter and I am having some difficulties. I have this repeatable segment:

[image]

It repeats 8 times.

I would like to create class or struct of:

```
frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Host 0", padx=5, pady=5)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
labela1 = Label(frame1, text="ID 21")
c1 = Checkbutton(frame1, text="Save images")
c1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
b11 = Button(frame1, text="Start host")
b12 = Button(frame1, text="Start app")
b13 = Button(frame1, text="Kill app")
b14 = Button(frame1, text="Turn off host")
labela1.grid(row=1, column=0)
b11.grid(row=1, column=2)
b12.grid(row=1, column=3)
b13.grid(row=1, column=4)
b14.grid(row=1, column=5)
labela12 = Label(frame1, text="Status", fg='#00f')
labela12.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=4)
```

and then populate GUI through *for loop.*
Is this possible in python?
I really couldn't find anything on the web for this type of problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a new class that inherits from Frame (or LabelFrame), and put all your code in the new class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common and easiest way of creating a custom widget is to start by creating a class that inherits from `Frame` or `LabelFrame`. Put anything you want inside that class. You can then use that class just like any other widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

class HostController(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, hostid, title):
        super().__init__(parent, text=title)
        self.hostid = hostid

        labela1 = tk.Label(self, text=f"ID {hostid}")
        c1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Save images")
        c1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

        b11 = tk.Button(self, text="Start host")
        b12 = tk.Button(self, text="Start app")
        b13 = tk.Button(self, text="Kill app")
        b14 = tk.Button(self, text="Turn off host")

        labela1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        b11.grid(row=1, column=2)
        b12.grid(row=1, column=3)
        b13.grid(row=1, column=4)
        b14.grid(row=1, column=5)

        labela12 = tk.Label(self, text="Status", fg='#00f')
        labela12.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=4)

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(5):
    hc = HostController(root, hostid=i, title=f"Host {i}")
    hc.pack(side="top", padx=4, pady=(0,4))

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much kind man. Have a nice day! <3